# iis rewritecond configuration with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I am using IIs6 as my webserver Here are my rewrite rules

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(html|htm|php|php2|php3|php4|php5|phtml|pwml|inc|asp|aspx|ascx|jsp|cfm|cfc|pl|cgi|shtml|shtm|phtm)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

The question is '%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f' seems doesn't work ,when I request the url like
http:// somesite/shopadmin/index.php, it still rewrite and jump to access http:// somesite/index.php?xxx ,

how to solve the problem?

I tried many times and It looks like the 'REQUEST_FILENAME' param is different as it works in apache?

Any helps would be thanks.

Comment: Do you really use htaccess in IIS ?! o_O

Comment: yes I am sure, css and txt file is ok and they can touch by client request but not php and html

Comment: Do you use this http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite ? Or : http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/

Comment: yes I am using isapi_rewrite The first RewriteCond works well, the others doesn't work, I guess there maybe some other softwares which installed in my server conflict with isapi_rewrite? I am not sure

Comment: I think isapi_rewrite do not full functionaly - check on isapi_rewrite site